# No route matches assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave

Whenever I try to upload a file with Carrierwave + s3 on my Heroku app I get this error "We're sorry, but something went wrong.", looking into my log I see this error:

```
    2012-08-20T21:18:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/" for 24.90.124.181 at 2012-08-20 21:18:56 +00002012-08-20T21:18:56+00:00 app[web.1]:2012-08-20T21:18:56+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets"):
```

I've did everything in this [tutorial](http://batsov.com/articles/2011/10/30/deploying-rails31-apps-on-celadon-cedar/) to deploy my app to Heroku on the Cedar stack, but I still see that error. I also had to add this to my application.html

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %> <%= javascript_include_tag "nested_form"%> <%= javascript_include_tag "application"%>
```

because having <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> only loaded "application.js"

I've tried everything I come across trying to get my uploader to work, but I don't know what the problem is. Everything works perfectly on my local app.

This is my app on [github](https://github.com/chrisbedoya/markt)
My Heroku [app](http://freezing-sword-8624.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

you can easyly replace the

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "nested_form"%>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application"%>
```

with: `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` if your `application.js` file do this imports.

the default imports are:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

if the problem is a missing javascript this should fix it

Other problem i see was this link inside `app/views/deals/show.html.erb`:

```
<%= image_tag(@deal.user.logo, :class => 'company_logo') %>
```

this line is returning this html:

```
<img alt="Assets" class="company_logo" src="/assets/">
```

this img src is invalid, and that is the error your are receiving on log.

if this image tag could link to an image path, like `/assets/avatar.png` i believe your problem will be fixed

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right problem, there is something wrong with the path.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Carrierwave, you need to do the following:

```
<%= image_tag(@deal.user.logo.url, :class => 'company_logo') %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag(@deal.user.logo.current_path, :class => 'company_logo') %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would have never found what the problem was.